# Asp.Net Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Whenever I try to do a System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() no matter what the URL I am calling I got the below error:

```
Exception Type: System.Net.WebException   
Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
Source: System

Stack Trace: 
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at WorldVision.Sitefinity.Data.Business.WebServices.Viocorp.PreparePostRequest(WebRequest webRequest, NameValueCollection parameters) in c:\Inetpub\Websites\WvaFEGit\CmsWebsite\WorldVision.Sitefinity.Data\Business\WebServices\Viocorp.cs:line 167
   at WorldVision.Sitefinity.Data.Business.WebServices.Viocorp.QueryWithParameters(ServiceType service, NameValueCollection parameters) in c:\Inetpub\Websites\WvaFEGit\CmsWebsite\WorldVision.Sitefinity.Data\Business\WebServices\Viocorp.cs:line 109
   at WorldVision.Sitefinity.Data.Business.WebServices.Viocorp.QueryWithParameters(String serviceName, NameValueCollection parameters) in c:\Inetpub\Websites\WvaFEGit\CmsWebsite\WorldVision.Sitefinity.Data\Business\WebServices\Viocorp.cs:line 87
   at WorldVision.Sitefinity.Data.Business.VioCorpVideoRepository.GetVideoByMediaId(String mediaId) in c:\Inetpub\Websites\WvaFEGit\CmsWebsite\WorldVision.Sitefinity.Data\Business\IVioCorpVideoRepository.cs:line 28
   at WorldVision.Sitefinity.Modules.Story.WebControls.Design.VioCorpVideoControlDesigner.BindPresentation() in c:\Inetpub\Websites\WvaFEGit\CmsWebsite\WorldVision.Sitefinity.Modules\Story\WebControls\Design\VioCorpVideoControlDesigner.cs:line 143
   at WorldVision.Sitefinity.Modules.Story.WebControls.Design.VioCorpVideoControlDesigner.BindVideo() in c:\Inetpub\Websites\WvaFEGit\CmsWebsite\WorldVision.Sitefinity.Modules\Story\WebControls\Design\VioCorpVideoControlDesigner.cs:line 136
   at WorldVision.Sitefinity.Modules.Story.WebControls.Design.VioCorpVideoControlDesigner.Button_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) in c:\Inetpub\Websites\WvaFEGit\CmsWebsite\WorldVision.Sitefinity.Modules\Story\WebControls\Design\VioCorpVideoControlDesigner.cs:line 187
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- L1 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Exception Type: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 210.247.216.66:80

Source: System

Stack Trace: 
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've looked at two different Urls from two different providers and I get exactly the same error apart from the IP address being different.

I've checked Firewall settings, IIS settings and server settings and nothing stands out.

To make matters worse the code works on an external server using IIS 7.5 with the same configuration but fails on an internal server.

I've also had the internal IP addresses added to the accepted lists of the two providers.

Therefore the code works fine externally and not internally. No differences in the code whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Comment: better on serverfault probably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this from the troublesome machine command prompt:

```
telnet 55.55.55.55 80
```

55.55.55.55 represents the IP address of the remote host. Make sure to include a space after it, before including 80 (the port).

If telnet can't connect, then there's definitely a problem between your application and the host application -- probably a firewall or related issue.

If telnet can connect, but your application still cannot, then you've legitimately narrowed it down to a very small thing (the application).

**Other Tips:**

- Proxy? [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001103/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Comment: It was the proxy. Forgot about IIS 7.5 running web requests under it's own account

Comment: In my case it was also the proxy. My customer forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you think that the exception is lying to you?

"the target machine actively refused it" means that the target machine received the connect request, but decided to refuse it instead of accepting it. This almost always means that there is nothing listening on the port the request was made on. I suppose it could mean that there was something listening, that it saw the connect request, and that it explicitly rejected it.

You need to find out from "the target machine" why it "actively refused" the connection attempt.